# Import a package doesn't return error, but doesn't work

Tags: python, import, package, shap

I  installed SHAP package using pip. when I'm using `pip freeze` I get:

```
...

    shap==0.40.0

...
```

I'm importing the package with `import shap`

when I check what does return `shap` I get:

[image]

If call for SHAP attribute  like:   `shap_explainer = shap.TreeExplainer(clf)` ,I get the error: `AttributeError: module 'shap' has no attribute 'TreeExplainer'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your python script file is called `shap.py`. What you are doing is actually importing your own script and not the `shap` module. Python [first looks in the script directory for imports](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path), and since it finds it, it stops searching and thus never finds the `shap` module you would need. Rename your script to something different and it should work.